# Setting column as hearder with values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables that join as category and subcategory.

This is my table

```
----------------------
Values   |  Category
----------------------
red      | Color
blue     | Color
green    | Color
male     | Gender
female   | Gender
singe    | Status
married  | status
```

Is it possible to be like this?

```
---------------------------------
Color     |   Status    |  Gender
---------------------------------
red       |  single     | male
blue      |  married    | female
green     |             |
```

And also when I add another category like `payment_type` i will automatically adds as header?

It will look like this

```
----------------------------------------------------
Color     |   Status    |  Gender    | Payment Type
---------------------------------------------------
red       |  single     | male       |
blue      |  married    | female     |
green     |             |            |
```

I do not know where to start in this query but I hope someone helps me with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A SQL query returns a *fixed* number of columns, so you cannot meet the last requirement with a simple query.  You need dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` & do aggregation :

```
select max(case when cat = 'color' then val end) as color,
       max(case when cat = 'status' then val end) as status,
       max(case when cat = 'Gender' then val end) as Gender,
       max(case when cat = 'payment_type' then val end) as payment_type
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by cat order by val) as seq
      from table t
     ) t
group by seq;
```

Note : If the `category` will not much increased then you use this approach else you can use `dynamic pivot` with `row_number()`

Comment: Will try this one. Will update for the result. Will also search for the dynamic pivot because most probably, the category and subcategory will increase.

Answer (score 0):

Using Pivot

```
;WITH CTE ([Values],Category,[Payment Type])
AS
(
          SELECT 'red'      , 'Color'  ,NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 'blue'     , 'Color'  ,NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 'green'    , 'Color'  ,NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 'male'     , 'Gender' ,NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 'female'   , 'Gender' ,NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 'single'    , 'Status',NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 'married'  , 'status' ,NULL
)
SELECT [Color],[Gender],[Status],[Payment Type]
FROM
(
    SELECT * 
    , ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY [Values]) AS Seq
    FROM CTE o 
) AS Src
PIVOT
(
MAX([Values]) FOR Category IN ([Color],[Gender],[Status],[Payment Type])
)pvt
```

Result

```
Color   Gender  Status      Payment Type
----------------------------------------
blue    female  married         NULL
green   male    single          NULL
red     NULL    NULL            NULL
```

Comment: Will try this. I will update you for the result. But how about when I add a new category. Will I still need another query?